# Is it possible to get records along with `distinct` query in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to pull all records with a distinct `name` that match `{ externalId: { $in: externalIds } }`. However, when I run this query, I only get back a list of the distinct names, not the actual records.

It it possible to have Mongo (using Mongoose) return me the records that are distinct? If it's not possible to easily do this (i.e. with a simple switch or built in function to add to the Mongoose chain) how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Many records may have the same name value; which ones do you want to return with the distinct name values? Just one with the proper name value but you don't care which one exactly? All of them smushed into an array?

Comment: Exactly - I don't care which record is returned as long as it's a record from that distinct set of values. So, if I've given Mongo 5 distinct `names` (and assuming all 5 names do exist in the model) I would like to have 5 records returned.